# How to install font "lmmath-regular.otf"?

Tags: xetex, ubuntu

I have downloaded a cv template from [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv), and I want to use it for my CV. This is the first time I am trying to use tex to do something. I have got stuck with the following error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "lmmath-regular.otf" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I have tried installing different fonts but situation is still same. I have tried reading different forums in the net but could not capture the point.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked out the sites http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm-math and http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have checked these sites. I dont know how to install a package from CTAN. I think it will require "tlmgr" to manage the package. I tried hard to find "tlmgr" in my system but still struggling.

Comment: Try replacing 'lmmath-regular.otf' in your code with 'latinmodern-math.otf'. [I don't want to download the zip if I don't have to so this is a guess but I'm assuming "lmmath-regular.otf" occurs somewhere in your code.]

Comment: The necessary package is `unicode-math`, which you already have. Download the OpenType font files (extension .otf) and activate them as appropriate for your operating system. (I can't tell if you've already done so.) Then, after executing `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, execute `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`. `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` should work too.

Comment: The opentype fonts may already be installed. They are included in TeX Live, for example. The issue, I think, is that lmmath-regular.otf no longer exists - the name is basically obsolete and has (I assume) been replaced by latinmodern-math.otf.

Comment: @cfr I tried finding lmmath-regular.otf in the template, but could not find it. Is it something automatically getting called ?

Comment: @bubble It isn't there. (I just downloaded the zip to look.) The class already loads unicode-math but the line which would set the maths font is commented out. According to unicode-math's documentation, it should therefore load latinmodern-math.otf as the maths font but it is apparently trying to load lmmath-regular.otf instead. Which distribution of TeX are you using and which version? I'm guessing you don't have the font installed *and* have an outdated version of unicode-math.

Comment: @cfr I am using `This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)`

Comment: Check unicode-math.sty to see what it says. My TL 2012 specifies the correct font but perhaps Debian did not update theirs completely.

Answer (score 2):

with current TeXLive 2013:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{LatinModernMath-Regular}
%% \setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}%% Alternative setting

\begin{document}

\[\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = 1 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using Tex Live 2012. Does it still apply ?

Comment: Yes, it should. Only the file name changed in the meantime but not the font name.